# nestjs return empty object after update to postgress

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am getting a issue lately...

As soon as I interact with the postgress DB and ask for a return of the object n get a blank `{}`, I am not sure as if I getUsers it returns an array with the object in the array.

Here is my code for reference:

```
 public async updateUserById(patchUser: CreateUserDto, userId: number, profile_image: any) {

        const user = await this._userRepository.createQueryBuilder('user')
        .where('user.id = :id', {id: userId})
        .getOne()

        if(!user) {
          throw new InternalServerErrorException(`User with id ${userId} does not exist`);
        }

        user.name = patchUser.name;
        user.surname = patchUser.surname;
        user.profile_image = profile_image.location;
        user.email = patchUser.email;

        return await this._userRepository.save(user);

      }
```

I have also tried:

```
 const foundUser = await this._userRepository.save(user);

 return foundUser
```

with no luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure TypeORM's `save` method *says* it returns something, but doesn't necessarily return it. [In this sample](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/blob/master/apps/typeorm-sample/src/cat/cat.service.ts#L25) I end up returning the object I created before the TypeORM call. In your case it would be

```js
...
user.name = patchUser.name;
user.surname = patchUser.surmame;
...
await this._userREpository.save(user);
return user;
```

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong because I can log out the user, but I can't return it. 

I am getting the same issue to getUserById. However I can return getAllUsers and I am doing the exact same method ...
```
public async getDriverById(driverId: number): Promise<any> {
        
        const driver = await this._driversEntiry.createQueryBuilder('driver')
            .where('driver.id = :id', {id: driverId})
            .leftJoinAndSelect("driver.user", "User")
            .getOne()
        
        console.log(driver);
        return driver;
    }
```